# How can I write text over an image, and overlay another image on it, in Python?

Tags: python, png, python-imaging-library

I need to put some text over a PNG image in Python, I need to put another image too over the first one.

So I'll have a base image (the same for every image created), a logo to put over it in the upper left corner, and a text all over the image (non-specific font, I just need to set the font size).

Could I use PIL, or another Library?

I searched over StackOverflow and Google too, but I could not find tips on how to do this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

PIL can do it:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageFont, ImageDraw
font = ImageFont.truetype("/usr/share/fonts/dejavu/DejaVuSans.ttf", 25)
img = Image.new("RGBA", (200,200), (120,20,20))
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)
draw.text((0,0), "This is a test", (255,255,0), font=font)
img.save("a_test.png")
```

The only error that can occur is not to find the font.
In this case you must change the code line:

```
font = ImageFont.truetype("/usr/share/fonts/dejavu/DejaVuSans.ttf",25)
```

Source: http://python-catalin.blogspot.com/2010/06/add-text-on-image-with-pil-module.html

Comment: In your codes, there're two lines about draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img), I think, the second one is not necessary.

Answer (score 9):

I think opencv is easier to use:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
image = cv2.imread('xxx.png')  
texted_image =cv2.putText(img=np.copy(image), text="hello", org=(200,200),fontFace=3, fontScale=3, color=(0,0,255), thickness=5)
plt.imshow(texted_image)
plt.show()
```

Note that the original image may be changed, so I add `np.copy` to protect it.
More details on the function is http://docs.opencv.org/2.4.8/modules/core/doc/drawing_functions.html?highlight=puttext#cv2.putText

The fontFace can be referred to https://codeyarns.com/2015/03/11/fonts-in-opencv/

Comment: Is there any way to obtain the pixel size of the resulting drawn text?

Answer (score 1):

PIL is one approach. You might also look at [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org), which also supports [compositing images](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/compose/) and putting [text into images](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/text/) (and lots of other stuff).

There's a python interface to ImageMagick through [PythonMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/api.php#python).